# Import data from CSV file to Mysql table through php

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

As explained in the title, I am trying to import data to my table through uploading the csv file to my php page. 
This is the code I got from [EggSlab](http://www.eggslab.net/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-php/)

```html
<?php
     
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = "Test";

     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
     
     
?>

<html>

 <body>
  
  <form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  
  <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $c = 0;
 while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
 $name = $filesop[0];
 $email = $filesop[1];
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `xl` (`Name`, `Email`) VALUES ('$name','$email')";

 }
 

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "You database has imported successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
}
}

?>
 </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that, when submitting the file, only the last row of my file gets inserted to the table. Any suggestion of a modification to make the code insert every row of the csv file ?

Comment: execute the query for each iteration in your while loop. Here, you just execute the request at the end, so one time and it's the last row of your csv

Comment: so, i'm not sure, but try to move your if else statement in the while loop

Comment: the query is inside the while loop.

Comment: yes, but the execution of the query is not

Comment: @Berserk Yeah you are right. I tried to move it inside and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA INFILE` it will be tremendously faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should fix your problem. You were not executing the query within the loop.

```html
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $c = 0;
 while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
  $name = $filesop[0];
  $email = $filesop[1];
 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `xl` (`Name`, `Email`) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "You database has imported successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
  }
 }
 

 
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, This worked perfectly. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

CSV file import below See Example:

```
   <?php 
           $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

           //Read the file
            $content = file_get_contents($file);
            //Split file into lines
            $lines = explode("\n", $content);

            //Find columns by reading first line

             for ($i = 1; $i <= 310; $i++) {
                $data = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);
                $name = $filesop[0];
                $email = $filesop[1];

                 $sql = "INSERT INTO `xl` (`Name`, `Email`) VALUES    ('$name','$email')";

        }
    }
```